# Error: PhpmyadminController could not be found

Tags: apache

When i am running phpmyadmin through apache ,browser is showing me this error --------Error: PhpmyadminController could not be found.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually the problem was in a corrupted installation of PHPMyAdmin, re-install it may solve the problem.